# CSGO won't open - Steam - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, games, steam, bug-reporting, error-handling

## **Important: I found a solution! Just look at my answer down below!**

Hello,

i started steam and i wanted to play some CounterStrike. Selected CS:GO and clicked play. First weird thing I noticed:
 It didn't say "Launching Counter Strike Global Offensive" and it didn't pop up in the dash. On my steam library it said "Counter Strike Global Offensive - Running". Everything was still fine on Ubuntu besides the fact that CSGO wont start. 
 Help would be appreciated!

As far as i know, this problem occurs on other Ubuntu 16.04 machines too. But i was able to play it 2-3 weeks ago, so it has to be because of an update of steam, csgo or linux...?

Thank you!

Comment: Open a terminal and run `steam`, now start your game and the terminal will tell you what the problem is, add that output to your question.

Comment: Done... I hope that will help to solve the problem!

Comment: OK run this `rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so` and reboot.

Comment: Solved it without doing that... see my answer for the solution. But thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: OK glad you got it fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

## **Solution to the problem:**

AMD has a new driver. Use the Beta version to solve the problem, it’s maybe not as stable as the open source Ubuntu driver but CS:GO (and other games on steam) will be playable again!

**https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx**

**Supported GPUs**, just install and enjoy your games again:  ​

> ​AMD Radeon™ **RX 480** // AMD Radeon™ **R9 M395X** // ​Radeon™ **RX 470**
>   //    AMD Radeon™ 
> **R9 M385** // ​Radeon™ **RX 460** // ​AMD
>   Radeon™ **R9 M380** // AMD Radeon™ 
> **R9 Fury X** //   AMD Radeon™ **R9
>   M270X** // AMD Radeon™ **R9 Fury** // AMD Radeon™ **R9 360**
>   // ​AMD Radeon™ **R9 Nano** //    ​AMD Radeon™ **R9 290X** //
>   ​AMD Radeon™ **R9 390X** //   ​AMD Radeon™ **R9 290** // AMD Radeon™
>   **R9 390** // ​AMD Radeon™ **R9 285** // AMD Radeon™ **R9 380X**
>   //    ​AMD Radeon™ R7 260X // ​​AMD Radeon™ R9 380
>   //    ​AMD Radeon™ **R7 260**

Information direct from the official AMD site.

**For all other / older GPUs from AMD** please use the open-source driver "**radeon**"!

(*Thanks to CelticWarrior for pointing out, that youve to use radeon than*)

Comment: It works only witht the supported GPUs. Older ones will have to use the open-source *radeon* driver.